# Revert split effect in a list

Tags: r

I have a list and I would like to convert it into a data.frame with two columns. The problem is that the length of list elements is not equal, here is a example of how my data looks:

```
my.list

$A1CF
 [1] "A1CF"    "APOBEC1" "CUGBP2"  "KHSRP"   "SYNCRIP" "TNPO2"  

$A2LD1
[1] "A2LD1"   "PRPSAP2" "RPL15"   "TANC1"  

$A2M
[1] "A2M"      "ADAM19"   "ADAMTS1"  "AMBP"     "ANXA6"    "APOE"
```

This list comes from a previous data.frame:

```
my.list <- split(df$V2, df$V1) 

df
      V1      V2
1   A1BG    A1BG
2   A1BG  CRISP3
3   A1CF    A1CF
4   A1CF APOBEC1
5   A1CF  CUGBP2
6   A1CF   KHSRP
7   A1CF SYNCRIP
8   A1CF   TNPO2
9  A2LD1   A2LD1
10 A2LD1 PRPSAP2
11 A2LD1   RPL15
12 A2LD1   TANC1
13   A2M     A2M
14   A2M  ADAM19
15   A2M ADAMTS1
16   A2M    AMBP
17   A2M   ANXA6
18   A2M    APOE
```

where the elements corresponding to AB1G were removed. I would like to revert the split effect to obtain the same structure:

```
new.df
A1CF    A1CF
A1CF APOBEC1
A1CF  CUGBP2
A1CF   KHSRP
A1CF SYNCRIP
A1CF   TNPO2
A2LD1   A2LD1
A2LD1 PRPSAP2
A2LD1   RPL15
A2LD1   TANC1
A2M     A2M
A2M  ADAM19
A2M ADAMTS1
A2M    AMBP
A2M   ANXA6
A2M    APOE
```

I have tried with: `df.new <- do.call(rbind, my.list)`, but obviously it didn't work.

Many thanks

Comment: I liked @baptiste answer. I would also like to suggest you look into the `plyr` package as a general framework for doing this kind of split/apply/combine work all at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using these dummy data,

```
ll <- list(a = letters[3:6],
           b = LETTERS[1:10],
           c = letters[1:2])

stack(ll)
```

or

```
reshape2::melt(ll, id=1)
```

or

```
plyr::ldply(ll, cbind)
```

should give you roughly the right format

Comment: Dear @baptiste, many thanks for your reply, but something "funny" is happening when I remove some items from my list and then revert the split effect with ldply. If I revert the splitted file and then I ran some analysis the removed files show up again...

Comment: there's no way I could answer this without being behind your shoulder watching your computer screen, you realise. If you have a new problem, please post a complete and minimal reproducible example as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of vectors, @baptiste provides more concise and general answers for list.

You can also apply `unsplit`, the inverse operation of `split`.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(V1 = c('A1BG', 'A1BG', 'A1CF', 'A1CF', 'A1CF', 'A1CF', 'A1CF', 'A1CF', 
                        'A2LD1', 'A2LD1', 'A2LD1', 'A2LD1', 'A2M', 'A2M', 'A2M', 'A2M', 
                        'A2M', 'A2M'),
                 V2 = c('A1BG', 'CRISP3', 'A1CF', 'APOBEC1', 'CUGBP2', 'KHSRP', 'SYNCRIP',
                        'TNPO2', 'A2LD1', 'PRPSAP2', 'RPL15', 'TANC1', 'A2M', 'ADAM19', 
                        'ADAMTS1', 'AMBP', 'ANXA6', 'APOE'))
my.list <- split(df$V2, df$V1)
newdat <- data.frame(V1=df$V1, V2=unsplit(my.list, df$V1))
```

If you have a list of data.frame from split, `unsplit` should be appropriate.

```
my.list <- split(df, df$V1)
newdf <- unsplit(my.list[!names(my.list) %in% 'A1BG'], df$V1[!df$V1 %in% 'A1BG'])
```

or

```
newdf <- do.call(rbind, my.list[!names(my.list) %in% 'A1BG'])
```

Comment: +1 also note that if you use `drop=TRUE` when subsetting `df$V1`, you don't need to specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.